# Getting subviews of a UIView within a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIScrollView that has UIViews in it, and in those UIViews are UIImageViews. I am trying to access the `UIImageViews`.

For proof of concept, I have a scrollview with a UIView, which contains a UIImageView in it, both whose tags are set to 0.

Code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

UIView *currentView = (UIView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:0];
UIImageView *currentImageView = (UIImageView *)[currentView viewWithTag:0];

[self bobbleView:currentImageView];

}
```

And then I am trying to bob that UIImageView up and down continuously (which is another matter in of itself, I can only get it to bobble once so I just that left that code in), but what is happening is the **entire UIScrollView and its subviews are bobbing**.

That code:

```
-(void)bobbleView:(UIView *)viewIn{

        viewIn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            viewIn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        }];

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Choosing 0 for the value of the tag may not be wise as this is the default value for any newly created UIView. Also `viewWithTag` traverses the children hierarchy (recursively, "downwards") which means that if you're not careful with your tag values, you may get back a view you didn't mean to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. Assign unique tags to the views and different to eachother. I bet that if you set a breakpoint in the call to bobbleView, your UIImageView object will be your UiScrollView and not the imageview nor the UiView... Use simply unique tags, like 100X fir the UIViews and 200X for the imageview

Comment: You called it....in retrospect 0 was probably the best worst choice for a tag name in the history thereof.

Answer (score 1):

The `viewWithTag` doc says:

```
Discussion
This method searches the _current view_ and all of its subviews for the specified view.
```

(emphasis mine)

What you are seeing is that:

```
(UIImageView *)[currentView viewWithTag:0]
```

returns

```
currentView
```

HTH